# Show comments on WordPress home page

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I've inserted the following code to the template loop (in the correct place), but it is not outputting any comments. Why?

```
<?php
    $withcomments = true; // force comments form and comments to show on front page
    comments_template( '', true );
?>
```

I'm trying to display comments for each post on the main-home-page stream of posts.

I'm using the [Twenty Ten](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyten/) theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this before the `<?php endwhile; ?>` of the loop in loop.php:

```
<?php
  $withcomments = "1";
  comments_template();
?>
```

Comment: I had to put it in the index.php of my template(inside of a loop that displays all posts), and it worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php global $withcomments; $withcomments = 1; comments_template(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way that doesn't involve editing PHP code.  First make sure you can create comments on other pages and if that is working, go back to the home page.

On the top right, click the gear icon to show settings and near the bottom of settings change the "page attributes" "template" from **"front page template" to "default template".**  Save and you will have comments.

*However*, you may lose other features of the home page (you can always change the template back).  For me I didn't lose anything.

Understand that a normal WordPress blog is intended to have comments on the blogs (posts), but not on the home page.  By default you shouldn't even have comments on any pages (just posts), but that is easily enabled.  That is why normally there aren't any comments allowed, but if you have a one-page site this is a problem.

Also note that there are many different themes and some **do** allow comments on the home page.