# How do I effectively get WordPress comments to display on home page?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, wordpress-theming

I can get the comments to display on the home page, but I was having 3 pretty major bugs. One of those bugs was done away with with an if statement. I am using the Yoko theme. In index.php I have a code snippet inserted between `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` and `<?php endwhile; ?>`. The inserted code is: `<?php if ($withcomments != 1) { $withcomments = "1"; comments_template(); } ?>`.

The problem I am having is that the first blog post has the comments displayed outside of the post itself. The other problem is probably unrelated to displaying the comments so I will not post it here, but it involves some pictures overlapping with the comments. You can see (if they are still up) the problems in action at www.flyfishingpursuits.org . Please do not post **any** comments on the page. I am doing this for someone else and please keep your "footprint" on the site non-existent. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please be concise in stating your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show comments on wordpress home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205002/show-comments-on-wordpress-home-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the wordpress get_comments() function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments