# WordPress: issues trying to get the comments to show up on the main page

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, comments

I'm trying to get the comments to show up on the main page but I'm having problems.

```
$withcomments = 1;
comments_template();
```

I've put the PHP code above in my index.php file. The comment box appears but for some reason the comments do not. Apparently this code is meant to make both the comments and comment box appear so I'm a little confused at why the comments aren't showing up. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show comments on wordpress home page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205002/show-comments-on-wordpress-home-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the function `wp_list_comments()` instead:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
</ol>
```

More info in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is not display the comments template if not on single post or page.
If you want to show then you have to create your custom funation which is fulfill your requirement.

Current function is located on wp-includes >> comment-template.php files line number 851.

Here is custom function to show comments listing, put it in functions.php theme file:

```
        function custom_comments_template( $file = '/comments.php', $separate_comments = false ) {
            global $wp_query, $withcomments, $post, $wpdb, $id, $comment, $user_login, $user_ID, $user_identity, $overridden_cpage;


            if ( empty($file) )
                $file = '/comments.php';

            $req = get_option('require_name_email');

            /**
             * Comment author information fetched from the comment cookies.
             *
             * @uses wp_get_current_commenter()
             */
            $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

            /**
             * The name of the current comment author escaped for use in attributes.
             */
            $comment_author = $commenter['comment_author']; // Escaped by sanitize_comment_cookies()

            /**
             * The email address of the current comment author escaped for use in attributes.
             */
            $comment_author_email = $commenter['comment_author_email'];  // Escaped by sanitize_comment_cookies()

            /**
             * The url of the current comment author escaped for use in attributes.
             */
            $comment_author_url = esc_url($commenter['comment_author_url']);

            /** @todo Use API instead of SELECTs. */
            if ( $user_ID) {
                $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND (comment_approved = '1' OR ( user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '0' ) )  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, $user_ID));
            } else if ( empty($comment_author) ) {
                $comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve', 'order' => 'ASC') );
            } else {
                $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND ( comment_approved = '1' OR ( comment_author = %s AND comment_author_email = %s AND comment_approved = '0' ) ) ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, wp_specialchars_decode($comment_author,ENT_QUOTES), $comment_author_email));
            }

            // keep $comments for legacy's sake
            $wp_query->comments = apply_filters( 'comments_array', $comments, $post->ID );
            $comments = &$wp_query->comments;
            $wp_query->comment_count = count($wp_query->comments);
            update_comment_cache($wp_query->comments);

            if ( $separate_comments ) {
                $wp_query->comments_by_type = &separate_comments($comments);
                $comments_by_type = &$wp_query->comments_by_type;
            }

            $overridden_cpage = false;
            if ( '' == get_query_var('cpage') && get_option('page_comments') ) {
                set_query_var( 'cpage', 'newest' == get_option('default_comments_page') ? get_comment_pages_count() : 1 );
                $overridden_cpage = true;
            }

            if ( !defined('COMMENTS_TEMPLATE') || !COMMENTS_TEMPLATE)
                define('COMMENTS_TEMPLATE', true);

            $include = apply_filters('comments_template', STYLESHEETPATH . $file );
            if ( file_exists( $include ) )
                require( $include );
            elseif ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . $file ) )
                require( TEMPLATEPATH . $file );
            else // Backward compat code will be removed in a future release
                require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/comments.php');
        }
```

now you can use this function in your template:

```
       <?php custom_comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

Hope this thread helps you. All the best ;)